# asp.net listview pop up image

Tags: jquery, asp.net, listview, popup

i m trying to do pop-up of image in listview with object data source.

i want when we click on image of the row as appear a pop up with this image.

in my code its always the first image in the pop up wathever the image that I click (because the pop up "build itself" in compilation and no in runtime.

```
            <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource2" OnItemDataBound="ListView1_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="ListView1_ItemCommand" DataKeyNames="HotelID">

                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <li style="">HotelID:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="HotelIDTextBox" runat="server" Width="200px" Text='<%# Bind("HotelID") %>' />
                        <br />
                        HotelName:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="HotelNameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("HotelName") %>' />
                        <br />
                        Country:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="CountryTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Country") %>' />
                        <br />
                        Town:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TownTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Town") %>' />
                        <br />
                        Image:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="ImageTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Image") %>' />
                        <br />
                        City:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="CityTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("City") %>' />
                        <br />
                        Country1:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Country1TextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Country1") %>' />
                        <br />
                        Rooms:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="RoomsTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Rooms") %>' />
                        <br />
                        <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                        <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
                    </li>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    No data was returned.
                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <li style="">HotelID:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="HotelIDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("HotelID") %>' />
                        <br />
                        HotelName:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="HotelNameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("HotelName") %>' />
                        <br />
                        Country:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="CountryTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Country") %>' />
                        <br />
                        Town:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TownTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Town") %>' />
                        <br />
                        Image:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="ImageTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Image") %>' />
                        <br />
                        City:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="CityTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("City") %>' />
                        <br />
                        Country1:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Country1TextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Country1") %>' />
                        <br />
                        Rooms:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="RoomsTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Rooms") %>' />
                        <br />
                        <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
                        <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Clear" />
                    </li>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemSeparatorTemplate>
                    <br />
                </ItemSeparatorTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li style="">
                        <table style="width: 100%;">
                            <tr style="width: auto; background-color: white;">
                                <td align="center">
                                    <div id="pageone" data-role="main" class="ui-content">

                                        <a href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window">
                                            <img src='<%# Eval("Image")%>' alt="Skaret View" style="height: 116px; width: 311px"></a>

                                        <div data-role="popup" id="myPopup" data-transition="flip" data-overlay-theme="b">
                                            <p>This is my picture!</p>
                                            <a href="#pageone" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-a ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right">Close</a><img src='<%# Eval("Image")%>' style="width: 800px; height: 400px;" alt="Skaret View">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="HotelNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HotelName")%>' Font-Underline="true" />
                                    <br />

                                    <asp:Label ID="TownLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Town")%>' />
                                    ,
                               <asp:Label ID="CountryLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Country")%>' />

                                    <br />
                                    <asp:Label ID="HotelIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HotelID")%>' Visible="false" />
                                </td>
                                <br />
                                <br />
                                <td align="right">
                                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="styled-button-2" Text="Book Now" PostBackUrl='<%#"~/BookHotel.aspx?HotelID=" + Eval("HotelID")%>' />
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>
                    </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <ul id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" style="list-style: none">
                        <li runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
                    </ul>
                    <div style="">
                    </div>
                </LayoutTemplate>
                <SelectedItemTemplate>
                    <li style="">HotelID:
                    <asp:Label ID="HotelIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HotelID")%>' />
                        <br />
                        HotelName:
                    <asp:Label ID="HotelNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HotelName")%>' />
                        <br />
                        Country:
                    <asp:Label ID="CountryLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Country")%>' />
                        <br />
                        Town:
                    <asp:Label ID="TownLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Town")%>' />
                        <br />
                        Image:
                    <asp:Label ID="ImageLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Image")%>' />
                        <br />
                        City:
                    <asp:Label ID="CityLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("City")%>' />
                        <br />
                        Country1:
                    <asp:Label ID="Country1Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Country1")%>' />
                        <br />
                        Rooms:
                    <asp:Label ID="RoomsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Rooms") %>' />
                        <br />
                    </li>
                </SelectedItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
```

thanks
(if there is a solution to do image button and onclick appear the popup it s well too.)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you have is that you reference the control with id myPopup and add the popup in the same itemTemplate. For each item you are adding another div with the same id myPopup. So a click on the third image will look for id myPopup and it will find the first element. There's no way to know the second or third popup is required.

What you can do is making sure your id's are unique so a click on the third image will look for the third popup. Todo this you shouldn't set the id yourself, but you can for instance use the ClientID which will contain the row index in it's id. Todo this you do need to set runat="server" for your popup div, so you can use the reference to it's ClientID (doing this by head, so can contain typos):

```
 <a href="#<%# Container.Item.FindControl("myPopup").ClientID %>" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window">
     <img src='<%# Eval("Image")%>' alt="Skaret View" style="height: 116px; width: 311px">
 </a>

 <div data-role="popup" ID="myPopup" runat="server" data-transition="flip" data-overlay-theme="b">
     <p>This is my picture!</p>
     <a href="#pageone" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-a ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right">Close</a><img src='<%# Eval("Image")%>' style="width: 800px; height: 400px;" alt="Skaret View">
 </div>
```

I don't think this is the best solution, but it does explain what went wrong in your concept regarding client-side ids in ASP.Net.

**Alternative single popup**
I don't think you need to see multiple popups if you click multiple images. If you always need to see the image of your last click your concept was ok, but the position of your popup wasn't.
So if you move your popup out of the ListView it will only be added once to the page, so a click will find the single popup control. You only need to use the same image to set in the popup using jQuery.

```
function SetImageInPopup() {
    //Get the imageUrl from the image inside the hyperlink
    var imageSrc = $("img", this).attr("src");
    //Now find the image in the popup
    var imgInpopup = $("mypopup > img");
    //Now adjust the image src
    imgInPopup.attr("src", imageSrc);
}

<a href="#myPopup" onclick="SetImageInPopup()"
```

**Alternative jQuery dialog**
If you don't need to use the specific popup logic, you can look into using jQuery's dialog and show the content of your link in the popup

```
function ShowDialog() {
    $(this).dialog(); //Specify specific dialog properties for your own dialog layout and behavior
}
```